# Removing index.php from codeigniter url on a wampserver envirement

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, oop

I want to remove index.php from codeigniter url where i have activated `rewrite_module` in apache server (im using wampserver) and removed index.php from config variable `$config['index_page'] = '';`  and added this code to `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

However, it still not working

Answer (score 0):

replace this line in config/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```